# .deps.json could not be found

Tags: .net

Follow this menu sequence:

File -> New -> Project -> ASP>NET Core Web Application (.Net Framework)

Build -> Build Solution

Get this error:

Error       C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RC2 Test\src\RC2 Test\error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RC2 Test\src\RC2 Test\Test.deps.json' could not be found.    RC2 Test    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  241

Searching for test.deps finds nothing.

Is "test" a hardcoded name for a unit test project?
dotnet --version says 1.0.0.0-preview1-002702

Edit:

I repeated the above steps but this time I selected Core Web Application (.Net Core).  I get the same error.

Looks like we cant use spaces in project names.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have the same issue, but I created a project with name "MyprojectWithoutSpaces" and the issue is gone. I suppose is a problem in the RC version

Comment: It is the folder name that can't have spaces. See **Line 241** of file `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.targets`

Comment: You sir, are great (Y)

Comment: I just want to add that this is present even in the RTW/RTM version.

Comment: I have the same error in a ASP.NET Core Mvc project. "...Service.deps.json' could not be found. ..."

Answer (score 5):

If you end up here after having similar problems running unit tests in a devops pipeline, you can fix the problem by ignoring the /ref directory in your test pipeline using the following pattern under Test files:

```
!**\ref\**
```

This ensures the pipeline ignores the extra test dll in the ref directory.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was that I tried to run unit tests using a dll from the `ref` folder.

As described by Pavol Kovalik in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/1270375/view.html:

Mine was caused by having 2 Project.Tests.dll files in build artifact directory

```
...\Debug
  net5.0
    ref
      Project.Tests.dll
    Project.Tests.dll
    Project.Tests.deps.json
```

As such the `vstest` was discovering 2 test files. First without `deps.json` file and another with it. My fix was to enforce that test file is in `net*` directory (could be `net5.0` or `net48` in my case) like this

```
- script: |
    dotnet vstest $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/bin/**/net*/*.Tests.dll --logger:trx
  displayName: Execute unit tests
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just created an empty file ex: `MyProject.deps.json` and now it's working fine.

I'm using `VS2015` update 3

Comment: Don't works. I got this error: `A JSON parsing exception occurred in [C:\Users\User\foo\bin\foo.deps.json], offset 0 (line 1, column 1): The document is empty.`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have an underscore in your project's name or its parent directory/directories. Remove that underscore if you find, and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Switching .net core from **x86** to **x64** could help. In my case I noteced **dotnet --list-sdks** displays path contains Programm Filex (x86), I had to edit Windows Path.