# Scaffolding error : deps.json doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm currently using VS2017 for developing .NET Core MVC Web

When I tried to create a new Controller from Add > Controller, I got this error

```
Error

There was an error running the code generator: "The specified deps.json
[C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\bin\MCD\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
\[project name].deps.json] does not exist"
```

When I explored the solution folder, I found that there are two folder in the bin directory, `Debug` and `MCD`.

```
bin
|
- Debug
 - netcoreapp1.1
  - ...
  - [project name].deps.json
|
- MCD <- this is where the scaffolding looks for deps.json
```

I noticed that I also got the same problem when debugging .NET Console app (which I created from `dotnet new console` cli command) from Visual Studio Code. The same problem faced in [.deps.json could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485968/deps-json-could-not-be-found)

Are there any .NET Core configs that I missed? Or this is a bug in .NET Core? I remember I didn't configure anything  prior from installing my .NET Core in VS2017

Comment: Does this project previously created with VS2015? Ever since I installed VS2017 my 2015 version doesn't work properly anymore.

Comment: @HamidMosalla no, this project is purely generated on VS2017

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the answer here : https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/113

Apparently, this is some kind of bug that appeared on HP computers. I'll quote from the GitHub issue :

> they have an environment variable called Platform, set to MCD which is why you are seeing this error.

This cause .NET Core to look for the file at MCD folder of your `bin`, instead of your normal `Debug` file. All you have to do is delete the variable or set it to nothing

Comment: What of Mac Users?

Answer (score 18):

In my case, this error appeared after the VS update. Don't know why, but what I did:

1. Go to your project folder and just remove the `bin` and `obj` folders.
2. Rebuild your project.
3. Add your new controller. It should work.

Perhaps it will help someone.

Comment: Just had this with VS 2019, followed the steps and they worked!

Comment: Was also having this exact issue with VS 2022 version 17.9.3, the solution provided by @Ivan Sivak worked.

Answer (score 7):

I had the problem with EF/add-migration in VS Comunity 16.9.3. My start project (bold in solution explorer) was set to one without EF. I switched that to the EF project and add-migration worked fine.

Comment: Can you explain how you switched and where ? I also had the problem with VS Community 16.9.3

Comment: @elQuique Set the project as the startup project from the solution explorer.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue with a `Blazor WASM` project, but the fix was to set the `Server-Project` as the start up project which can be done by right clicking the project in Visual Studio and then running the Command `Update-Database`

Comment: thanks for that, last answer in the list and was the best solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

The file VS 2017 is looking for in

> [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\bin\MCD\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
>   [project name].deps.json]

seems to be found at

> [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
>   [project name].deps.json]

So I just copied the content from the second folder to the first and it worked.
No need to change environment variables

Comment: Im getting this in VS2019 on a Lenovo; there is no Platform variable. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
2. dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
3. dotnet ef
4. dotnet ef migrations --project YourProject.Data --startup-project YourProject.UI add InitialCreate
5. dotnet ef database --project YourProject.Data --startup-project YourProject.UI update

Comment: I was hoping this would work, not for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in visual studio 2019. I cleaned and rebuild the solution and the problem was resolved. I have an HP machine.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem under VS2017. My solution was to delete the variable Platform in Environment Variables. Also your must reboot your VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can change the `launch.json` by adding the *MCD* folder to the string of the `"program"` argument

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error working with VS 2022 when trying scaffolding my MSSQL database to blazor app from Package Manager Console.
It was resolving using the same order from CMD after shifting to the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

**If nothing works try this:**

Set the project that contains the entities that you wish to create in the database as the default project.

*The case could be that you are trying to add a migration on a project that does not have the required entity objects.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to scaffold in other project which is not your startup project then try setting the project where you want to scaffold as your default startup project. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue in VS 2022 with a Blazor WASM and API project, and found this SO entry in my Google search. I tried a few of the suggestions in this thread to no avail. However, a comment made by FrqSalah about restarting VS was the answer for me, combined with setting the appropriate start up project(s).

Right Click solution --> Properties --> Set appropriate start up project(s) --> Clean --> Rebuild Solution --> Restart VS.

I was able to add a migration and update the database after following the above steps.