# MVC Scaffolding Error, deps.json does not exists

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following along with the [Contoso University](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) and I'm running into the HP Computer Platform issue mentioned [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757322/scaffolding-error-deps-json-doesnt-exist) about the scaffolding creation error saying deps.json does not exists in a certain folder.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional and using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

I have changed my Environment Variable, Platform, from `BPC` to nothing by using `set Platform=` in command prompt.

Still I get an error when I try to `Right Click on the Controllers folder > Add > New Scaffolding Item... > MVC Controller with views, Using Entity Framework > Fill out the form by picking a Model class and Data context class > Add >`

```
Error

There was an error running the selected code generator:
'The specified deps.json [C:\...\bin\BPC\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\ContosoUniversity.deps.json] does not exists'
```

I have tried cleaning cleaning the solution, restarting Visual Studio 2017, and rebooting my computer to no avail.
Not sure what else I should do to prevent this error. Any suggestions? I feel like copying the files into the BPC folder is a workaround, but not the best solution.

**Edit 1**

I noticed that the Environment Variable, Platform, got reset to `BPC`, so I deleted it and rebooted again. Didn't come back.

Now when I try to create the scaffold I get this error:

```
Error

There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString
  at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b_6_0()
  at
Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
  at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)'
```

**Edit 2**

Setting the Platform variable back to `BCP` manually brings back the original error.

Copying and pasting all files from `...\ContosoUniversity\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\` to `...\ContosoUniversity\bin\BCP\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\` gets me past that error, but the error from Edit 1 comes back.

Seems I have two separate problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I made a typo in appsettings.json

I had `"ConnectionString"` instead of `"ConnectionStrings"` with an 's'

That was causing my `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString` error

So, to solve my original problem, follow these steps for Windows 7. (10 shouldn't be much different):

`Windows key > Right click on Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables... > Under System variables find Platform > Highlight Platform > Delete > OK`

Answer (score 0):

make sure .json file exists in path specified. and let me know about that what you find.

Comment: It's not there. That's part of the problem. Visual Studio or the project should be looking in `bin\Debug\...\ `, where the files are located, not `bin\BPC\Debug\...\ ` where it's empty.