# Could not copy the file deps.json because it was not found. Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4919

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I just updated VS 2019 to 16.9.4 version. Sometimes I am getting three errors on rebuilding solution:

> Could not copy the file deps.json because it was not found. Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    4919
> Could not copy the file runtimeconfig.json because it was Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  4919
> Could not copy the file runtimeconfig.dev.json because it was Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  4919

Rebuild will be success when I do clean and rebuild. When I try rebuild one more time after rebuilding, I am getting these errors. I found couple same questions here:
[.deps.json could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485968/deps-json-could-not-be-found)
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16386
I tried their worarrounds but it couldn't help me. Does anyone know solution? My projects are in .NET 5